# Index in the given list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

[11,12,13,14, 15, 16, 17,18,19,20]. 
Find the index of the integer key in the given valley list.

Comment: Do you want us to do your homework for you? That's not the right the place for it unfortunately. If you want, you can post the code you have so far and we will help you get out of a jam

Comment: We won't do your homework for you if you don't show any effort at attempting to solve it yourself. Please see [ask]

Comment: Take a look at the [index()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index) function of lists :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [index()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index) function of lists :)

EDIT: The function you're describing might be implemented like this:

```
def create_valley_list(input_list, cut_index):
    # make sure list is sorted
    sorted_list = sorted(input_list)

    # cut list at given index
    list_before_cut_index = sorted_list[:cut_index + 1]
    list_after_cut_index = sorted_list[cut_index + 1:]

    # reverse left part
    list_before_cut_index.reverse()

    # return joined list
    return list_before_cut_index + sorted_list[cut_index:]
```

Afterwards, you can use this function on a list. For your example, this would be:

```
input_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]

valley_list = create_valley_list(input_list, 8)
```

Now you can get the index of any item in the list with the index() method.

```
print(valley_list.index(8))
```

which returns 2.

But be aware of the fact that this only works reliably if no item is in the list twice, since the index() method returns only the index of the first found occurrence!

Answer (score 0):

vc pode usar o método index, exemplo:

> [13, 11, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 14, 15, 16, 17].index(8)
>
> 2

Comment: Please use English on this site. You can visit https://pt.stackoverflow.com/